# javascript - a small error with event.keyCode

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing a Javascript to detect a certain alphabet in a text `input` by changing a `<div>`'s color. The code I have written below doesn't seem to be working, how can I solve this problem?

```
<input onkeypress="myFunction(event)"></input>
<div id="a" style="color:blue">text</div>
<script>
function myFunction(event) {
  var x = event.which || event.keyCode;
  if (x == 81) {
  document.getElementById('a').style.color = red;
} else {
  document.getElementById('a').style.color = green;
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Set "green" &"red" instead of green and red. They are string values

Comment: BTW, don't use [`onkeypress`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onkeypress), and don't use [`event.keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode). These are deprecated. Look at the big red notices on mdn...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use [`KeyboardEvent.keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) it is no longer in the standard. Use [`KeyboardEvent.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) or [`KeyboardEvent.code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code). They are also a lot easier to remember as they hold the character or name of the key pressed.

You problem was that you attempted to assign variables to the color property rather than the strings `"red"`, `"green"`. It is far better to create the colors as a style and add or remove the style rule (CSS). That way you can have far more than just the color change.

### Example

```js
inputEl.addEventListener("keypress", inputEvent);
function inputEvent(event) {
    if (event.code === "KeyQ") {
        colDiv.classList.add("greenKey");
    } else {
        colDiv.classList.remove("greenKey");
    }
}
```

```css
.greenKey {
    color: green;
}
div {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<input id="inputEl" placeholder="Type Q Green else Red"></input>
<div id="colDiv">Colour</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
//red and green are not defined but 'red' and 'green' should be there
```

```html
<input onkeypress="myFunction(event)"></input>
<div id="a" style="color:blue">text</div>
<script>
function myFunction(event) {
  var x = event.which || event.keyCode;
  if (x == 81) {
  document.getElementById('a').style.color = 'red';
} else {
  document.getElementById('a').style.color = 'green';
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments you should assign string literals, so "red" and "green" need quotation marks.

Some remarks:

- you are using deprecated `onkeypress` and `event.keyCode`. Instead use `onkeydown` or `oninput` and `event.key`.
- it is better practice to bind event handlers via JavaScript code, not via HTML attributes.
- in HTML the `<input>` tag does not come with a closing tag, so remove that.
- As in both cases you assign a color style, you could use the ternary operator.
- You seem to want to detect a certain letter (uppercase "Q") in the input. But then you should not just look at the key that is being pressed, but also at the other characters that are already in the input. So use the `oninput` event, and check the value of the `input` element to see it *includes* the letter "Q".

```js
let div = document.getElementById('a');
let input = document.querySelector("input");

input.addEventListener("input", function (event) {
  a.style.color = input.value.includes("Q") ? "red" : "green";
});
```

```html
Don't include a "Q": <input>
<div id="a" style="color:blue">text</div>
```